# Create new Entity Object in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm hoping someone could shed some more light on my confusion with JPA entities in a Spring Boot project. I've heard that one should never call `new` in a Spring project. I understand that this is to allow Spring to manage all of the beans, and getting a bean can be done through injection or through the application context explicitly.

However, it's not clear to me how to get a new JPA Entity. If I have a class annotated with `@Entity` and a repository class that handles my data access, how do I obtain a new entity object in my service layer?

I've included `@EntityScan` in my application's main class so I would assume that Spring is aware of the entity. But when I try to get it through the ApplicationContext an exception is raised. This makes sense because I don't believe the `@Entity` annotated classes are Spring Beans, and I don't think it would be correct to also annotate it with `@Component`. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

I'm currently using the `new` keyword and creating the entity objects myself in the service layer. A very simple example is below:

#### entities/User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;

    // Getters & Setters ...
}
```

#### repositories/UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

#### services/UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void createAndSaveUser(String username) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);

        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And we could assume that there was some other controller classes that would utilize the service layer.

In this example I am explicitly calling the `new` keyword in the service class method `createAndSaveUser`. Is this the correct way to do it or should I be getting some prototype bean from Spring that maps to my JPA entity?

Comment: Here is a good read related to how components get scanned. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Spring/article.html

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the extra documentation, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In spring you can autowire/inject your beans, components or services. However the entity should not be autowired since these interactions are done through your repository. Your repository **can** be autowired.

When you want to create a new instance of your entity you **are allowed** to call `new`, because this does not need to be managed by spring. You can simply use the autowired repository to save it in the database. This also works the other way around because obviously you would need the autowired repository to retrieve your entity.

So yes, your method is correct.

I hope this makes it clearer for you, if you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are doing is completely valid in spring. In example you have provided above I could figure out that you want your entity class object itself to store the values. Its absolutely correct.
You have to use `new` keyword to achieve that.
If you still wish to not create a new object for your Entity you have another option to do it through Bean/POJO/VO  classes and mapping your entity object with these classes.

But Still i will tell that whatever you have done is completely fine.

Actually the object you are creating is for storing value purpose not just because you have some method is there in your class and so you are bound to create `new` Object to be able to call that method(As we do in normal java project).In spring that is handle by `@Autowired` annotation to create object. 
Simple example is you will be auto-wiring your repositories in your service classes.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds good to me: you create your entity and then ask the repository to store it.. no problem with Spring.

have you checked this out? :

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

have fun

Comment: I've looked at the link, I guess I just needed some validation! Thanks!